# Embedding a self-contained Java Server Faces or Servlet (?simulated) web app inside of an applet (for distribution of a sample application)

Tags: jsf, web-applications, servlets, applet, portability

(After giving this some thought, I don't know what I meant by saying applet. What I should have said was standalone Swing app with Swing browser).

I don't have access to a URL, or a Java Web Server (and especially) on the computer of the person to whom I would like to send sample work. I would like to be able to code up a Java Server Faces version of their current web site, in a short amount of time, to demonstrate skill level. What I am wondering is if there is any easy way to put either a Servlet, or a Java Server Faces application into an applet, and by harnessing the ?JSF Servlet?, or Servlet. I might/would like to simulate an HTTP message (by sending an http message by local method call) to the applet running Servlet, so that I can process the servlet request and send the response back to a swing-based browser window running in the applet. I might just open up a local ?TCP/IP port (in the applet) and send the request from the browser to the JSF ?Servlet or Servlet that way? With JSF, I am unsure if there are complex context management concerns that require a Server container, or whether there is some way to interface with a standalone JSF package, through a servlet, and find that the JSF api is taking care of handling the application details, all the way up to the point where the response is broadcast.

I have read the JSF specification through a few times. I know that there is loading of nodes pertaining to the elements displayed in the web page, but I am uncertain whether the (say) Glassfish Server actually takes care of managing various aspects of initializing lifecycle stages, initializing them apart from the JSF packages.

If it is not readily achievable through JSF, then Servlet would be ok, I could even use Jetty if necessary, but I would like to keep the size of the total applet as small as possible (and avoid debugging with Jetty, if all I need is a port:

***I only need a single instance of the app, running on a browser, (both run) in one applet, where the browser does not communicate with anything outside of the applet).

I also might like to use JSP, but I am uncertain whether JSF packages take care of that, whether the ?JavaEE main package takes care of that, or what packages take care of that. I could avoid using JSP, but it might be nice to use Derby in combination with JSP and backing beans, to handle the database-generated elements in the web pages.

If I did not cover anything, you might mention it. If I think of it later, I might write it down in this posting.

What I would like is this:

Applet(
SwingWebBrowser <-(?port in applet)-> ?Some container class(Servlet <--> JSF or JSP/HTML)

I think that I might need something to load the servlet, besides just writing a few lines in the applet, but this might not be the case. Also, I am unsure what will process the calls to the database when I have the JSP code in those pages. Returning static HTML pages is simpler though, and I could just generate them using Java code and calls to a database through that code.

Thank you.

Comment: *"If I did not cover anything, you might mention it."*  A question.  There are plenty of '?' in there, but no question as far as I can tell from skimming the hits on '?'.  As an aside, I doubt you will be able to make this work reliably in an applet.  Your best bet might be to lay out a few bucks for a server for a month, and load the project there.

Comment: Actually, the standalone Swing app is what I was thinking, rather than the applet. Standalone swing app with swing browser window.. I don't have a few bucks to shell out.

Comment: I just write question marks in front of (or after) items that I'm not certain about, when I write down any design notes that make assumptions.

Comment: <head-desk/>   What *is* **your** ***question?***

Comment: If I load a JSF Servlet class and send it messages, will it otherwise process the requests? If not, how many more classes do I have to deal with, in order to get the JSF package to process the request (?including writing lines to a JSP page from a database call.) I write the question mark because I am not sure if JSF is what part of the (say) Glassfish Server that would normally perform this operation. It's ok, if you don't have this answer, because I might be able to debug the app in eclipse, (if) on ?Glassfish, and see what the answer is, in terms of how much of request processing was JSF.